# Why dotNET is creating a DLL for WinForms?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I'm migrating from .NET Framework to .NET (Core).

I've just realized that .NET Core applications created by VS2022 always have a DLL:

[image]

And if I examine my EXE's details:

[image]

Why is the original filename set to the DLL? Can I change it to `WinFormsApp2.exe`?

With .NET Framework, no DLL was generated, and original filename was always set to the current EXE file. Can I reach this with .NET (Core) too?

Comment: Why do you want to change it? (It is possible to modify the resources - include the version info - of an executable using native APIs, but why bother?).

Comment: Just for *cosmetic* reasons :)

Comment: OK, but than think about it that way: That "Original Filename" leaves a "visible" trace inside the executable, for which it was meant for: starting the "WInFormsApp2.dll". ;-) If the executable is renamed, that trace remains.

Comment: Valid point! Thanks. And (for learning purposes): if I wish to hide this trace, can I somehow change the Original Filename field?

Comment: Start [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/adding-deleting-and-replacing-resources), you are looking to update the [version info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/version-information).

Answer (score 0):

.net core applications are cross-platforms which is why DLL is generated as part of the build process. DLL contains the compiled so you can run the app on platform which have .net core runtime.

you can change the setting in visual studio for a different DLL name.

on the other hand,.net framework applications are built as single executable file (EXE) that contains all the application's code and dependencies which is to be run only on windows OS.

Answer (score -2):

It is normal to have .dll extension file because it is library which contains your code and allows to run program for multiple time in windows.